# Sudo doesn't work

Tags: sudo

I edited my sudoers file in /etc and after that I can't use sudo anymore. I get this whenever I issue the command:

```
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 30 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 30
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

How to solve it?

Comment: That's why you're supposed to use `visudo` for editing `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: related question -> [what-are-the-differences-between-sudo-su-visudo-chroot-and-gksu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/197772/what-are-the-differences-between-sudo-su-visudo-chroot-and-gksu)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Boot into recovery mode from the GRUB menu (hold the SHIFT key during boot to reveal this menu), enter the root shell.

1. First you need write permission to edit sudoers, so run

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   ```
2. Then use `visudo` and revert your mistake. `visudo` will check if the resulting sudoers file conforms to the required syntax.

   By default `visudo` uses `vi` as editor, but you can tell it to use your favourite text editor with the `EDITOR` environment variable, e. g.:

   ```
   EDITOR=nano visudo
   ```

Comment: Please include in your answer an advice to use `visudo` to make any change to the `sudoers` file.

Answer (score 27):

Had the same problem,

```
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 25 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 25
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Easier way to fix it is :

```
pkexec visudo
```

Comment: No joy; `The program 'pkexec' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install policykit-1`

Comment: Seems to be installed in 14.04. This fix also works for corrupt overrides in sudoers.d, via `pkexec visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/myOverrides`.

Comment: it's installed as default in 15.04 too. Worked great for this situation.

Comment: I believe this only works if your current user has a password, eg., it fails for those who ssh into machines with an unset password.

Comment: @tedder42 I think so as well

Answer (score 2):

This fixed the same problem for me:

```
pkexec chmod 440 /etc/sudoers

pkexec chmod 775 /etc/sudoers.d

pkexec chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/README
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also edit `/etc/sudoers` with any text editor you like:

```
EDITOR=gedit visudo
```

would use gedit for it. But you should run it from shell. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to read error-Messages.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the default `sudoers` file for Ubuntu:

```
# /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

Defaults    env_reset

# Uncomment to allow members of group sudo to not need a password
# %sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

I hope it will help you my friend.

Comment: As of Ubuntu 12.04, this is no longer the default (since `sudo` is now the group that confers administrative abilities, though in upgraded systems `admin` still exists and serves its usual function).