# Sending ICMP Echo Request Using Raw-sockets

Tags: networking, c, ping

I compiled a c program that sends ICMP Echo Request Using Raw-sockets and also receives one back (ping).

However, for some reason, even though I am the ROOT I still seem to be denied by the permission. I added a screenshot

[image]

Comment: You're using `sudo` where you shouldn't and not using it where you should,

Comment: Is this on WSL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between sudo, su, visudo, chroot, and gksu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197772/what-are-the-differences-between-sudo-su-visudo-chroot-and-gksu)